# Terminology - Sum each element in a vector with each element of other vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors, vector-analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $C$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with

$$C_{ij} = a_i + b_j.$$

Above, $C$ is defined in an entry-wise fashion; i.e., a single entry of $C$ is defined in terms of single entries of $a$ and $b$. If possible, I would like to describe the entire matrix $C$ using the entire vectors $a$ and $b$ using a simple closed-form notation. Does  such a notation exist?

Comment: Let $o$ be the vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where all of its entries are $1$. Consider $ao^T + ob^T$ and $oa^T + bo^T$. I think one of those is the one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix},$ $b=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\\vdots\\b_n\end{pmatrix},$ $c=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}.$
$$C=ac^t+(bc^t)^t=ac^t+cb^t.$$